# React native run iOS build failed error: Multiple commands produceEntry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, react-native

After installing react native project dependencies and execute `react-native link`, this error comes out when I run the command `react-native run-ios`.

```
    Build system information

    error: Multiple commands produce ...
    1) Target 'ReactNativeNavigation' (project 'ReactNativeNavigation') has copy command from '.../node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/ios/ReactNativeNavigation.h' to '.../ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h'
    2) Target 'ReactNativeNavigation' (project 'ReactNativeNavigation') has copy command from '.../node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/ios/ReactNativeNavigation.h' to '.../ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h'
    
    ** BUILD FAILED **

    Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app
    An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
    Failed to install the requested application
    An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
    Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
    
    Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/Info.plist
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

More information about my environment:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0
xcode 10.0
node v10.11.0
npm 6.4.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was `react-native-navigation` bug and fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/commit/b5d300f0506e3e8098de5be0390b58eea32eb085)

A temporary fix was to go to `ReactNativeNavigation.xcodeproj` in your project hirerchy (Should be under Libraries), and then choose `ReactNativeNavigation` under **TARGETS** (and not **PROJECT**), then select Build Phases > Copy files, and check `Copy only when installing`.